# Image not loading consistently in SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, image-display

I have a SharePoint 2013 site that contains a document library that contains images. These images are being used in pages using the insert image option.

The problem is sometimes these images do not load on the page and whenever it does not load on the page the image does not load when the direct URL is accessed as well. It just shows a cross mark.

I have checked the URL multiple times and it's the same and this issue is inconsistent.

The image format is.JPG and sizes are in the range of 1.5MB

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you check in, publish and approve the picture that you want to load on the page.

Did you modify the format of the picture before uploading it? Modify the format of picture may damage the picture. Try to change picture extension to PNG then upload the picture again.

And you could try to upload the pictures to the picture library first, then add them in the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the pictures.

I had the same issue when users have changed format of image by renaming extension in file name and then uploaded to SharePoint. Try to save broken image on local computer and open in internet explorer. If an image will not open correctly try to change file extension to PNG or BMP.